# Is there a way to use `exec` in a where clause?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to query an instance of SQL Server to give me a list of databases that contain a table of a specific name. This is what I have so far...

```
select name
from master..sysdatabases
where (exec('use ' + name + '; select 1 from information_schema.tables 
  where table_name = ''TheTableName'';')) = 1;
```

But I get the following error messages

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'name'.
```

What is the correct syntax to use call `exec()` in a where clause? Or is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use `exec` in a `where` clause. How about some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT name = NULL WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  UNION ALL SELECT name = ''' + name + ''' 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name)
  + '.sys.tables WHERE name = ''TheTableName'')'
  FROM sys.databases;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Powershell was built for this:

```
$server = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server ".";
foreach ($db in $server.Databases) {
   $t = $db.Tables | where {$_.Schema -eq 'YourSchema' -and $_.Name -eq 'TableName'};
   if ($t -ne $null) {
      $db.Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is it better to go out to PowerShell instead of solving it from T-SQL where the OP is working?

Comment: Probably Okay in this instance, but powershell was not made for this, if you can do it in the dbms (within reason), you should.

Comment: Why?  Lack of convolution in dynamic SQL.  Notice how I don't have to jump through hoops to escape quotes?  Also, MS has said that powershell is the future of administration.  Why not take every opportunity to apply it where it makes sense.  And I think it makes sense here.  Lastly, the OP said, and I quote: "Or is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?".  Why yes, yes there is.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL statement will give you all of the database names that contain the table you are looking for:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'USE [?]; select ''?'' from information_schema.tables where table_name = ''TheTableName''' ;
```

Comment: Bear in mind this is an undocumented sp though. Also you get a result set for each database, not a result set with all the relevqant databases in it. Okay for admin stuff, I'd have deep think before I used it in application code though.

Comment: Agreed! I assume that the need to search through database schemas for a table was an admin need.

Comment: I like that this solution is terse, but I'd prefer one result set rather than one result set for each result.

Comment: Not only is this undocumented and unsupported, it is *fundamentally broken* and Microsoft is unlikely to ever fix it. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx and http://mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  temporary table to get information back from exec.

Try this

```
Create Table #TableLocations(DatabaseName varchar(255) not null)
Declare @databaseName VarChar(255)
Declare @QueryString VarChar(255)
Declare DatabaseNameCursor Cursor For Select [Name] From sys.databases
Declare @TableName VarChar(255)
Select @TableName = 'Put your table name here'
Open DatabaseNameCursor
Fetch Next From DatabaseNameCursor Into @databaseName
While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
  Select @QueryString = 'Use ' + @databaseName + ' Insert into #TableLocations Select ''' + @databaseName + ''' From information_schema.tables Where Table_Name = ''' + @TableName + ''''
  Exec(@QueryString)
  Fetch Next From DatabaseNameCursor Into @databaseName 
End
Close DatabaseNameCursor
DeAllocate DataBaseNameCursor
Select * from #TableLocations
Drop Table #TableLocations
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the results from the Stored Procedure in a temporary table, and then add it to the WHERE clause